Why MDDH is DDH when k in Matrix D is 1?
I am reading a paper Multi-authority ABE for Non-monotonic  Access Structures, when the author defines the DDH problem in preliminaries. The definition is 
I find it is a type of Matrix DDH when $k=1$.
Then I read Asymmetric Cryptography Primitives and Protocols in 5.2.2.1. It says

D1 is simply the classical decisional Diffie- Hellman assumption.

but no reason or proof is displayed. I can prove if DDH is hard, MDDH1 is hard by constructing a tuple $\{g^a, g^b, Z, (g^b)^2\}$ by DDH (if $Z=g^{ab}$, it is constructed by DDH tuples, it is not otherwise).
However, I failed to prove

If MDDH1 is hard, DDH is hard.

Is it discussed in any website, books or papers?

With overwhelming probability $1-1/p$, the element $[\![ \mathbf{a} ]\!]_s$ can be written in the form $(g,g^a)$ for some generator $g$ of $\mathbb{G}_s$ and $a$ uniform mod $p$. And then, you can write $[\![ \mathbf{u} ]\!]_s$ as $(g^b,g^c)$ for uniform $b,c$.
Thus, letting $r=b$, the assumption is literally saying that $(g,g^a,g^b,g^{ab})$ is indistinguishable from $(g,g^a,g^b,g^c)$, which is the standard DDH assumption.

Thank you. Your idea is also helpful  when proving both direction.
